# Mocha Test for NodeJS Function not calling Callback

Tags: node.js, facebook, testing, request, mocha.js

I have a function that sends a message to a facebook user using a facebook page.

```
// send text message to an user
function sendTextMessage(sender, text, callback) {
    messageData = {
        text: text
    }
    request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        qs: { access_token: token },
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            recipient: { id: sender },
            message: messageData,
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
            callback(-1);
        } if (response.body.error) {
              console.log('Error: ', response.body.error);
              return -2;
          } else{
            console.log('Ok: ' + JSON.stringify(body));
            callback(1);
            return response;
        }

    });
}
```

My problem is, when I run this code on the command line, it works fine, however, I'm trying to create a test for this using mocha.

```
it('Text Message', function(){
    var fb_answer = function(res){
      // first schema to be compared
      var fbTextAnswerSchema = {
        "title": "fb answer schema v1",
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["recipient_id", "message_id"],
        "recipient_id": {
           "type": "string"
        },
        "message_id": {
           "type": "string"
        }
      };
      expect(res).to.be.jsonSchema(fbTextAnswerSchema);
    }
    messenger.sendTextMessage(sender, "[TEST] Testing send text message", fb_answer);
  });
```

And when I run mocha on the command line calling this test, it not only passes, but it also does not print the body of the response.

Basically what is weird here is that, when I run using node the code prints the response, and when I run with mocha, it doesn't, which makes me think that the callback of the request is not called.

I need to pass a test function as callback to this function in order to treat the response.

Why isn't the response printed? And why is the callback is not called? Is there a better way to test this kind of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this inside a `describe` block. All mocha hook functions have a `done` callback which can be used to tame async calls and setup your environment before making assertions

```
// first schema to be compared
var fbTextAnswerSchema = {
    "title": "fb answer schema v1",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["recipient_id", "message_id"],
    "recipient_id": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "message_id": {
        "type": "string"
    }
};

var res;
before(function(done){
    messenger.sendTextMessage(sender, "[TEST] Testing send text message", function(response){
        res = response;
        done()
    });
})

it('Text Message', function(){
    expect(res).to.be.jsonSchema(fbTextAnswerSchema);
});
```

or just

```
it('Text Message', function(done){
    messenger.sendTextMessage(sender, "[TEST] Testing send text message", function(response){
        expect(res).to.be.jsonSchema(fbTextAnswerSchema);
        done()
    });
});
```

It is a matter of style which on you choose

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Is there a way of not using res as global? Because I would like to test three different functions like this and it doesn't sound like a good solution to make three global variables. Also, I need to  to run other two variations of sendTextMessage, is there a way of create a before statement for each test?